# How do I make this function run in a loop with multiple sheet id's?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple Id's I want to run this script but have no experience with loops.
Can someone please help me with the formula and explain it to me?
Regards
James

```
function myFunction() {
    var master = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYID1'); 
    var resultsheetname = ("Results - " + todaysdate); 
    var sheet = master.getSheetByName(resultsheetname);
    var sheetname = ("Vote - " + todaysdate);
    var sheetid = sheet.getSheetId();
        
    sheet.getRange('c16').setValue(sheetid " and "sheetname);        
}
```

Comment: Spend some time learning about JavaScript. Mozilla Developer Network is a good place to start as they have guides pointed to people that doesn't have programming experience. In any case, good questions on this site , no matter of the poster programming experience, include a brief description of the search/research efforts made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `forEach` method to loop through the list of Spreadsheet IDs.

```
const SS_ID = ["id1", "id2"...]
SS_ID.forEach(function(id) {
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); 
  var resultsheetname = ("Results - " + todaysdate); 
  var sheet = master.getSheetByName(resultsheetname);
  var sheetname = ("Vote - " + todaysdate);
  var sheetid = sheet.getSheetId();        
  sheet.getRange('c16').setValue(sheetid " and "sheetname);
});
```